# nill return from dataWithContentsOfFile absoluteString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I save a text file using writeToUrl method in nsstring class. The data gets saved. I confirmed it by opening the file however when i call

```
NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[tempFileURL absoluteString]];
```

i get a nill value for tempData. And by the way guys, its mandatory for me to use [tempFileURL absoluteString] when retrieving data.

```
NSString *testString = @"Hello World";
NSString *fileName = @"TestFile.txt";
NSString *folderName = @"FolderName";

NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *localFolder = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:folderName isDirectory:YES];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:localFolder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];
NSURL *tempFileURL = [localFolder URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSError *error = nil;

[testString writeToURL:tempFileURL
                atomically:YES
                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                     error:&error];
NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[tempFileURL absoluteString]];
```

Comment: What do logs of tempFileURL and [tempFileURL absoluteString] show?

Comment: -3 for passing `nil` for the error parameter and not checking return status twice.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `path` method when you have a file URL within your local file system and you want to get the path of that file. Do not use `absoluteString`. The `absoluteString` will include the `file://` scheme at the start, which is not valid in a path.

Answer (score 0):

The error is reading the file and the path. There is a mismatch between URL and path.

Use either:

```
NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[tempFileURL path] options:0 error:&error];
```

or

```
NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tempFileURL options:0 error:&error];
```

dataWithContentsOfURL